# SilverStripe 3.6.3 un-publishing unexpected results

Tags: silverstripe

I have a question about unpublishing pages in 3.6.3. If I unpublish a page, all of its descendants also get unpublished so I have to re-publish all of them when I re-publish the parent page. I do not remember this happening in the past with other versions. This is not very good if it is a feature as I can no longer tell if some of the child pages were unpublished before I unpublished the parent page so It is possible that by batch publishing all of them, I may published pages that should not yet be published. Is this a bug or a feature?

Comment: Good question - do you need to unpubish it or do you just need to hide it from the menus?

Comment: An example where unpublishing child pages along with the parent page is if a page is accidentally unpublished or if a set of child pages are not ready to be published but are in various states of competion. It is nice to be able to unpublish the parent and publish the child pages as they are completed then publish the parent page to allow the section to be viewed. This is not a case of hiding from menus as there is a mechanism for that.

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm this happened in prior versions (I checked as far back as 3.3.2). For what it's worth, reviewing the source code, it looks like this "feature" also exists in SilverStripe **4.x** and above as well (e.g. [v4.6](https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-cms/blob/4.6/code/Model/SiteTree.php#L333)).

It looks like this was caused by the `enforce_strict_hierarchy` setting under `SiteTree`. This apparently defaults to `true` and means that whenever a page is deleted (regardless of the "stage", e.g. live vs. draft) it will result in *all child pages also being deleted*.

Technically when you unpublish a page, it deletes it from the "live" stage. Because this was a deletion, it then ends up cascading to all child pages as well. As a result, the net effect is that when you unpublish a page all child pages appear to have been unpublished as well. This is a weird setting which I just discovered unexpectedly after 384 pages suddenly got unpublished. Particularly because this also means that you have to choose between this unexpected functionality of unpublishing (deleting) everything under the current page, or, have the possibility of lots of orphans sitting around in the database.

Anyway, to workaround this, add this to your site's `_config.yml` file:

```yaml
SiteTree:
  enforce_strict_hierarchy: false
```